# Can I filter a whole workflow on circleci?

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

Based on circleci documentation I can [filter jobs based on the branch](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#branch-level-job-execution) :

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  dev_stage_pre-prod:
    jobs:
      - test_dev:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: dev
      - test_dev2:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: dev
      - test_dev3:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: dev
```

Can I do something similar at the workflow level ? Putting a `filters` block just under the workflow name does not work and CircleCI returns a build error because my schema could not be parsed. I want to avoid repeating the same filter for each job in my workflow.

All I have found is [this post](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/workflows-seem-incomplete/13461) but it is a bit old and does not give any solution.

Comment: Since this is YAML, you just define a YAML top-level block and then use a reference to merge it into place. Oddly enough, the Wikipedia article on YAML is an excellent reference for this. [See my example here](https://github.com/halfer/cd-demo-container/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml) for references in action.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

If the jobs are parallel (as you have them here) then either use a YAML anchor/alias or just do it manually.

If the jobs are meant to be sequential, the filter is only needed on the first job.